# Xcode: Creating new configuration xcode project can't find framework headers files

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode8

I created a new Xcode configuration duplicating "**Debug**" configuration:

[image: Duplicate of "Debug" configuration]

But the problem is when I try to run/build, it cannot find the header from a framework I'm using:

[image: "header file not found" error message]

The debug configuration is working fine.

Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong or if I need to do something else besides duplicating the configuration?

I'll really appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you try the usual: Xcode > Product > Clean Build Folder... and restart Xcode?

Comment: @meaning-matters , Yes, I did and also delete everything DerivedData

Comment: It's a while ago I did this and can't help you. Really sorry. Last suggestion: Are you sure the framework is included (which header is missing)?

Comment: @meaning-matters, the framework is proprietary framework. The point is why is failing with the copy of the configuration.

Comment: using cocosPod ? try to pod update